# using "i++" in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

Hi
I have a question that can I use such a this code:

```
        if (low != mid && mid != high) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= mid; i++) {
            boolean bool = Determinate.isPointLeftSide(a, auxiliaryListTwo.get(i), auxiliaryListTwo.get(i + 1));
            if (bool == false) {
                p = auxiliaryListTwo.get(i);

            } else {
                boolean bool1 = Determinate.isPointRightSide(a, auxiliaryListTwo.get(i + 1), auxiliaryListTwo.get(i));
                boolean bool2 = Determinate.isPointRightSide(a, auxiliaryListTwo.get(i + 1), b);
                if (bool1 == true && bool2 == true) {
                    p = auxiliaryList.get(i + 1);
                }
                else{
                    i++;
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

I have used "i++" in the else part ,is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it correct?

If want the code to have the effect of `i = i +1`, then it is correct. Since you already increment i in the for statement, i will be incremented twice if it reaches that `else`. As long as you have analyzed the implications of this in your code, you should be fine. In your case, you won't have to worry about out of bounds issues because the loop at the top terminates if `i<=mid` and there's no code after the i++. However, the loop will never be run for certain values of i when i++ is reached as it effectively skips an iteration.

Here's a quick refactoring of your code to remove useless variables. For maximum clarity, you should put the variables back but use more informative variable names, like `boolean isAToTheLeftOfB = ***`. Comments are your friend!!

```
package example;
        if (low != mid && mid != high) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= mid; i++) {
            if ( ! Determinate.isPointLeftSide(a, auxiliaryListTwo.get(i), auxiliaryListTwo.get(i + 1))) {
                p = auxiliaryListTwo.get(i);

            } else {
                if ( Determinate.isPointRightSide(a, auxiliaryListTwo.get(i + 1), auxiliaryListTwo.get(i)) && Determinate.isPointRightSide(a, auxiliaryListTwo.get(i + 1), b) ) {
                    p = auxiliaryList.get(i + 1);
                }
                else{
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Thanks to [Vladimir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292836/using-i-in-a-for-loop/4292917#4292917) for pointing out that you should use the [continue statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) instead of incrementing the counter directly. This is definitely more clear and less error prone.

Answer (score 7):

the basic rule is that you don't change the counter variable(`i` here) in any way inside the loop. If you want to skip the current iteration you should use `continue;` statement.

Comment: +1:  The `i++;` statement is bad practice, sure path to maintenaince hell.

Answer (score 2):

Can I offer a couple of style tips?

Try not to use double negatives. E.g.

```
if not condition
  task for false
else 
  task for true
```

This can be difficult to read. It's clearer to say

```
if condition
  task for true
else 
  task for false
```

It's also not normal to say:

```
if (bool == false)
  do something
```

We normally say

```
if !bool
  do something
```

And we would not use a variable called bool but would name according to purpose. E.g.

```
boolean isLeftSide = Determinant....
```

Answer (score 1):

Not commenting on your code particularly but it does not feel right to do that. A for loop is self managed in the sense that i is incremented for you. When you also manipulate the value of i the results are difficult to predict. Potentially you can find yourself going off the edge of a collection when you do such.

Comment: I agree that manipulating i values is not the best idea and that it can go over the edge of collections, but in his case there's not much to worry about. Since i++ is at the very end of the code, it effectively just skips one iteration. The very next thing that happens is a check to see if i is still within the accepted bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `while` loop, for things to look more logical. This is perfectly legal, but not a 'good' way to code.

Answer (score 0):

```
`for (int i = 0; i <= mid; i++)
```

already increments if its **true or false**  so if u use again in else it increments twice